# Apache's 404 page not shown in IE but works in firefox?

Tags: apache-2.2, internet-explorer-8, http-status-code-404

The related configuration is like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

And it works in firefox,but when in IE it's not shown(IE's default 404 page is shown instead)

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internet Explorer will show a "friendly" error message instead of whatever it receives from the web server if what it receives is below 512 bytes.

Increase the amount of data in the response (even if that means adding a big `<!-- comment -->`)